# difference between nvidia-smi command and conda list cudatoolkit on anaconda prompt

Tags: cuda, anaconda, nvidia

when I type on anaconda prompt:

```
nvidia-smi
```

it states that I have cuda version 11

but when I type

```
conda list cudatoolkit
```

I get 10.1.243

1. what is the difference between the commands?
2. what is the difference between cuda and cudatoolkit?
3. is the difference in versions a problem? if so, how to fix it?

Comment: `nvidia-smi` tells you what version of CUDA the installed *driver* package supports, it doesn't tell you anything about what version of CUDA is installed.

Comment: it answers 1/3 of my question. I still don't know what is the difference between cuda and cudatoolkit, and how to fix this mismatch of version. will downloading and installing cuda toolkit 10.1 fix the problem?

Comment: You don't need the versions to match. It is all explained [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html) (it's for Linux, but applies to Windows too).

Comment: cudatoolkit is a misnamed conda package -- it contains the bare bones cuda runtime libraries required to support the CUDA accelerated python packages and nothing else. You need to separately install a supported driver and if you want anything else, like nvcc or other components from the NVIDIA cuda toolkit, you need to install that yourself. The "mismatch" is irrelevant -- as long as the version nvidia-smi shows is as large or greater than the runtime you are trying to use, everything will just work